# How to convert a pandas string variable to float without rounding or down-casting?

Tags: python-3.x, string, converters

I have 5000 rows of prices as a pandas object, which I want to transform into two numerical columns of minimum and maximum and get the average.The prices look like this($0.89-1.5, $1.75-2.86).
When I try to to use to_numerical, astype(float) or other methods , they automatically downcasted. The problem is , that values like 0.89 they turn to 0 which is actually wrong and decreases accuracy. How can i fix this?

Example:
Here is an example of how my data look like and my steps to get the minimum price column:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwCsg.png)

replace ',' with '' to set price to european locate. E.x. 1,500.65 -> 1500.65

```
df_1['product_price']=df_1['product_price'].str.replace(',','')
```

get first part of the string (before '-') as minimum price

```
df_1['Min price']=df_1['product_price'].astype(str).str.split('-').str[0]
```

keep only numerical digits

```
df_1['Min price']=df_1['Min price'].str.extract('([0-9]\w{0,})', expand=True)
```

transform to float

```
df_1['Min price']= df_1['Min price'].astype(float).round(2)
```

*What I want is something like this :*

```
Price   Price_final
'0.89'  0.89
'0.98'  0.98
'1.75'  1.75
'2.14'  2.14
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can't reproduce. `pd.DataFrame({'Price': ['0.89', '0.98', '1.75', '2.14']}).Price.astype(float)` shows correct float values with dtype `float64`

Comment: This problem can't be reproduced with what you provide. Please, modify your question to include the way  you are creating the initial dataframe to startwith, Try to include even some sample rows of your source file (or rows with the exact same format as you have there if the data is confidential).

Comment: I rephrased the question and provided some sample code. Is this help?

Comment: yes, the example of the data layout and the previous steps you are taking help. Now  it is possible for one to answer the question. The main problem seems to be you are taking no steps to strip the extra contents on the cells, like the "(aprox.)" text, or the € sign